# Is it possible to set a background for the reachability feature?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

With reachability I mean this iOS feature (a feature that makes it easier to use apps with just one hand, it is executed by double-tapping the home button without actually pressing it):
[image]

Is it possible to set a background instead of the black screen?

Comment: No, there is no Api in the iOSSDK that allows you top set the background.

Comment: are you talking about app's window background?

Comment: It would be nice of Apple to implement an this, i'm sure there are better, prettier ways to make the top-end of the screen reachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. When you tap the button the system lowers the entire UIWindow of your application so the black background is actually outside your sandbox and you can't touch it.

Comment: It seems that you are right, I was hoping that at least setting the background color of window would make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do so.